# garageband splice 10 second clips

Tags: garageband

I want to take 10 clips of songs from my itunes on my mac into garageband (or something) this is a just a small little thing I want to do for a party so we can play name that tune like you often hear on radio stations

how ever I can't even seem to figure out how to get them into garage band

any help you could give me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve this. I'm going to describe the way I use, and find easiest to describe.

Find the tune you want in iTunes. Right click, and choose "show in Finder".

A Finder window will pop up, with the MP3 (etc) file for your song highlighted.

Drag that file to the tracks window of Garageband.

Once it's in, you can trim off the parts you don't want, by splitting the part and deleting the unwanted pieces.

Comment: Thank you I know it was easy just couldn't figure out how to get it into garage band

Comment: also if you fiddle about with the right hand pane in Garageband, I think there's a media browser, which might give you access to iTunes content. Why you can't just drag from iTunes to Garageband, I don't know.